Sumifs rows based on header
Is there a way to do sumifs in a range which criteria is based on several headers without using a helper column?

In the table A1:D21, I wanted to create a summary below it (A23:D28) showing the total sum of each Team Leaders of their total Inbound and Outbound, and showing the grand total.
Normally what I would do is add a helper column adding the name of team leaders beside those agents to simply do sumifs. Is it possible to do this without the help of a helper column?

Update Added Another Sample Close To What I Am Currently Working On

All Team Leaders and Agents are unique, I just duplicate the tables as the one I am working on has a lot of set of tables that are placed like this.




Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %




Team Leader A




Team Leader A




Team Leader A





Agent 1
100
50
50%

Agent 1
100
50
50%

Agent 1
100
50
50%


Agent 2
100
60
60%

Agent 2
100
60
60%

Agent 2
100
60
60%


Agent 3
100
70
70%

Agent 3
100
70
70%

Agent 3
100
70
70%


Agent 4
100
80
80%

Agent 4
100
80
80%

Agent 4
100
80
80%


Agent 5
100
90
90%

Agent 5
100
90
90%

Agent 5
100
90
90%


Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%


Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Team Leader B




Team Leader B




Team Leader B





Agent 6
100
50
50%

Agent 6
100
50
50%

Agent 6
100
50
50%


Agent 7
100
60
60%

Agent 7
100
60
60%

Agent 7
100
60
60%


Agent 8
100
70
70%

Agent 8
100
70
70%

Agent 8
100
70
70%


Agent 9
100
80
80%

Agent 9
100
80
80%

Agent 9
100
80
80%


Agent 10
100
90
90%

Agent 10
100
90
90%

Agent 10
100
90
90%


Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%


Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Team Leader C




Team Leader C




Team Leader C





Agent 11
100
50
50%

Agent 11
100
50
50%

Agent 11
100
50
50%


Agent 12
100
60
60%

Agent 12
100
60
60%

Agent 12
100
60
60%


Agent 13
100
70
70%

Agent 13
100
70
70%

Agent 13
100
70
70%


Agent 14
100
80
80%

Agent 14
100
80
80%

Agent 14
100
80
80%


Agent 15
100
90
90%

Agent 15
100
90
90%

Agent 15
100
90
90%


Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%


Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %

Name
Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Team Leader D




Team Leader D




Team Leader D





Agent 16
100
50
50%

Agent 16
100
50
50%

Agent 16
100
50
50%


Agent 17
100
60
60%

Agent 17
100
60
60%

Agent 17
100
60
60%


Agent 18
100
70
70%

Agent 18
100
70
70%

Agent 18
100
70
70%


Agent 19
100
80
80%

Agent 19
100
80
80%

Agent 19
100
80
80%


Agent 20
100
90
90%

Agent 20
100
90
90%

Agent 20
100
90
90%


Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%

Totals
500
350
70%



















Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Entered Calls
Accepted Calls
Accept %


Team Leader A
500
350
70%

Team Leader A
500
350
70%

Team Leader A
500
350
70%


Team Leader B
500
350
70%

Team Leader B
500
350
70%

Team Leader B
500
350
70%


Team Leader C
500
350
70%

Team Leader C
500
350
70%

Team Leader C
500
350
70%


Team Leader D
500
350
70%

Team Leader D
500
350
70%

Team Leader D
500
350
70%


Totals
2000
1400
70%

Totals
2000
1400
70%

Totals
2000
1400
70%




Here is one way of doing this:


=LET(
     _Filler, SCAN(,IF(D1:D21="Total",A1:A21,""),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Output, FILTER(HSTACK(_Filler,B1:D21),TEXTAFTER(_Filler&"|"&A1:A21,"|")="Totals"),
     VSTACK({"","Inbound","Outbound","Total"},_Output, HSTACK("",MMULT({1,1,1},DROP(_Output,,1)))))


Another Method without using LAMBDA() helper functions, the following solution may or may not work with the actuals, but here is what I have assumed as per the given data in the OP, if all the agents are same for each team leaders then we can wipe them out using UNIQUE() to grab only the distinct ones, yes it is to be noted again, that i am deliberately doing this based on the given data that the agents will not be different and then with manipulation with DROP() , TAKE() and FILTER() function we can achieve the desired output. All these depends, again this is completely based on the given sample data and pattern based.:


=LET(
     _Data, A1:D21,
     _Teams, UNIQUE(TAKE(_Data,,1),,1),
     _Vals, DROP(FILTER(_Data, TAKE(_Data,,1)="Totals"),,1),
     _Combined, HSTACK(VSTACK(_Teams,""), VSTACK(_Vals, MMULT({1,1,1}, _Vals))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("",DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1)), _Combined))


EDIT: Updated solution based on the edit with new sample data posted by OP at 2024-05-01 21:14:40Z


=LET(
     _Data, A1:D32,
     _TeamLeaders, TAKE(FILTER(_Data, INDEX(_Data,,2)=""),,1),
     _Vals, DROP(FILTER(_Data, TAKE(_Data,,1)="Totals"),,1),
     _Totals, MMULT({1,1,1,1}, TAKE(_Vals,,2)),
     _Bottom, HSTACK("Totals",_Totals, TAKE(_Totals,,-1)/TAKE(_Totals,,1)),
     _Middle, HSTACK(_TeamLeaders,_Vals),
     _Top, HSTACK("",DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1)),
     VSTACK(_Top, _Middle, _Bottom))


Suggestion: Put the following formula in the name manager and define as SUMMARY
=LAMBDA(array,
   LET(
       _Data, array,
       _TeamLeaders, TAKE(FILTER(_Data, INDEX(_Data,,2)=""),,1),
       _Vals, DROP(FILTER(_Data, TAKE(_Data,,1)="Totals"),,1),
       _Totals, MMULT({1,1,1,1}, TAKE(_Vals,,2)),
       _Bottom, HSTACK("Totals",_Totals, TAKE(_Totals,,-1)/TAKE(_Totals,,1)),
       _Middle, HSTACK(_TeamLeaders,_Vals),
       _Top, HSTACK("",DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1)),
       VSTACK(_Top, _Middle, _Bottom)))


And now use the following formula below each table as :


=SUMMARY(A1:D32)


=SUMMARY(F1:I32)


=SUMMARY(K1:N32)



This works perfectly! Now since I am really not familiar with the Lambda and these are new functions to me. My next problem is how I can make this flexible since I am going to use it for multiple columns. But this is great thank you!

I tried moving your formula below the table, and just simply duplicate the entire columns including the formula you created and it works fine. I can just do it if I have more columns needed to add moving forward and the formula would pull any data above it.

@Harvey I dont think there should be any problem if you have multiple columns, because if i assume if you add columns for additions numbers then it should before the last column Totals, and if it is some other text columns related to team leader then you should be updating your post. otherwise i dont see any issue with the formula.

@Harvey ok so could you let me know what you are looking for? also in your posts its no where mentioned that you will be having multiple columns.

yeah, the post is just a simple sample for easier understanding of what I wanted to achieve, but now I just realized the formula you gave me, it works great but I am having hard time to apply it to my real assignment which composes of multiple set of that by columns

sure hold on a moment and I'll share an excel file as a sample with you.

@Harvey see I have posted another method, and have given some notes so it helps you to understand

I got it sir! I am going to read it now. I've also updated my post to show you another sample that I wish to achieve using the formula you gave me.

@Harvey is this is the final one right, i hope there shall be no more changes?

@Harvey I have updated my answer based on your new sample data, also it is not LAMBDA() based and easy to understand, hope you can make this workout.

WOW this looks amazing! I am going to try this again tomorrow! You have a good night sir thank you again!

@Harvey you are yet to accept my answers on your older posts. This one

wow that was so long ago! I must have forgot that. I've accepted your answer. Thank you!
